# How a deprecated function can crash WordPress site while upgrading

Tags: plugin-development, upgrade, deprecation, compatibility

It is said that deprecated functions used in plugins & themes can crash a wordress website while upgrading to newer version, I want to see an example of deprecated function that can cause a crash.

Can someone show me an example?

Many Thanks!

Comment: They'll trigger a fatal error if they were finally removed in the new version yet were still in use. But nothing different than a regular PHP "call to undefined function" (or WSOD if debugging is disabled).

Comment: @TheDeadMedic Should be an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Where...

The following files hold the deprecated functions:

- `~/wp-includes/deprectated.php`
- `~/wp-includes/pluggable-deprectated.php`
- ...

Take a look at them and then through their replacement functions, where the calls to `_deprecated_function()` happen.

### Why...

Normally a crash shouldn't happen. In the "real" PHP world, you'd get an `E_DEPRECATED` Warning. In WordPress you'll get a `trigger_error()` return caused by `_deprecated_function()` calls. The second `trigger_error()` argument isn't used, so it defaults to `E_USER_NOTICE` and won't stop your application from running.

### How to turn it off...

You can turn this off either by using `define( 'WP_DEBUG', false );` or by using a MU-Plugin that sets the filter to false:

```
<?php
defined('ABSPATH') or exit;
/** Plugin Name: (#105686) Turn off deprecated Warnings */
add_filter( 'deprecated_function_trigger_error', '__return_false' );
```

Comment: nice answer but I want to see an example of why WP sites crash while upgrading, can you please give me an example?

Comment: @TahirYasin I have no example, as there is none. Deactivate debug or use the MU-Plugin and you're fine. As I explained, it's an `E_NOTICE`, not an `E_ERROR`. The only thing I could imagine is that it echos inside some call where nothing should echo. For example during plugin activation. Just update your question with a real world example. So far you're too abstract.